How Can I Open the Property Expressions Editor within a SSIS Custom Task?
I have created a custom SSIS task using a Windows Form for the GUI.  I'd like to be able to open the Property Expressions Editor window with a button click.  The image is from a third party control that seems to be able to open the editor.

I've looked around and cannot find any usable information outside of using the generic IDtsTaskUI interface.

It's times like this, that I sure miss codeplex. The SSIS team had excellent examples of how to build custom components. Not sure on the Property Expressions editor there, but  here's at least an example of how to roll your own custom UI https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/part-2-adding-a-custom-ui-to-the-connection-manager/ I haven't really kept up with the custom task/component scene since 2012 was released I know I've seen questions on custom component development here but I'll be danged if I can find what I half remember answering
